How to specify several alternative conditions (OR operator) for single case statement? (Or Alternatively, where is shell case syntax description?)
I want something like this:
time="1m"
case "$time" in
    *h*) 
    *m*) 
    *s*) 
        echo "handling several cases for h, m, s tokens" ;;
    *)
        echo "handling other cases" ;;
esac

How to achieve this for POSIX shell?

Does this answer your question? AND operator in case statement?     No, it’s not the same question, but it does contain the answer to this question.

Note that we explicitly allow and encourage self-answered questions, and we tolerate (if you’ll pardon the phrase) “dumb questions”.  But asking and self-answering a question that is trivially answered by reading the documentation strikes me as abuse of the mechanism.

I kindly disagree about "dumb question". Dumb question in my understanding is the question answer to which can be easily found. And I have not easily succeeded with this. The first three results from googling "shell case syntax" do not mention syntax for | (OR) operator. Here on Unix Stackexchange was only related question that you've mentioned - AND operator in case statement. And thanks to it I found right link to the case syntax.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' That is why I thought that It is right thing to do to a bit simplify search of the answer for the next researchers by creating this question.

I've updated title of the question so it will be more relative and more simple to find by search queries

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' Also I disagree that the current question is a duplicate of AND operator in case statement. But after me accepting proposed by you related question the system marked the current question as duplicate and closed it. I think it is better to open it since obviously they are two different questions. If you have rights to open question please consider to open it.

@AntonSamokat the problem with search results is that they vary a bit. From your link in a private window, the very first result for me is https://www.howtogeek.com/766978/how-to-use-case-statements-in-bash-scripts/ which contains an entire section on "Using Multiple Patterns in a Clause", the second is a very short tutorial so doesn't mention anything too complicated, and the third has "The | operator separates multiple patterns" in the second section itself.

As for reopening, on the one hand, you're right that question asking for an OR statement and one asking for an AND statement are different, but on the other hand IMO any reasonable person searching for an  "OR operator" for a case statement would look at a post on "AND operator"for case statements simply because the two are so related that it's highly likely one will mention the other. One does not simply ignore related concepts in search results because search quality in general is that bad. I'd prefer just having one post that discusses both, whether that be this one or the duplicate.

@muru I have the same links in the search results but there are two problems with them: 1) They do not have full case syntax like you provide with the link in answer for the current question. 2) Examples there written for #!/bin/bash, not for #!/bin/sh. Probably they also will be working in sh but I do not know. And I'm interested specifically in general POSIX case syntax.

@muru It is not possible get results for search query "OR operator for case statement" both in search engine and here on Unix Stackexchange. And when I needed that information I did not come up with the idea that I must search by "AND operator for case statement" like query.

@muru Because of that I propose either to open the current question or to update the name of the question AND operator in case statement to more relevant that it can be easily found for "OR condition". For example to: "AND / OR operators in case statement. Shell case syntax."

@AntonSamokat for the latter you are welcome to suggest an edit to that question

@muro I've proposed this name: How to specify AND / OR operators (conditions) for case statement? What is shell case syntax?. Waiting for approval.

When looking for information on the syntax of shell language, the first place to look should be the manual page of a particular shell. For most users, this will be man bash. All users of Unix-like systems should be familiar with programs man and less to browse manpages with. As stated, simply self-answering this trivial question (yes, it is trivial) is an abuse of the system. Any part of any manpage could be reposted as a question and answer if this was allowed.

The syntax of the case command is:

case word in
    [(] pattern1 ) compound-list ;;
    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list ;;] ...
    [[(] pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
esac

Syntax for case also can be printed in bash by the command below (it is suitable for POSIX shell as well):
$ help case


case: case WORD in [PATTERN [| PATTERN]...) COMMANDS ;;]... esac

Execute commands based on pattern matching.

Selectively execute COMMANDS based upon WORD matching PATTERN.  The
`|' is used to separate multiple patterns.

Exit Status:
Returns the status of the last command executed.

Syntax in man bash:
case word in [ [(] pattern [ | pattern ] ... ) list ;; ] ... esac

can be found by ^ *case pattern.
Example of usage:
time="1m"
case "$time" in
    *h*|*m*|*s*)
        echo "first case"
        echo "handling several cases for h, m, s tokens" ;;
    *)
        echo "seconds case" 
        echo "handling other cases" ;;
esac

References and related questions with examples:

Conditional Constructs
AND operator in case statement?
bash - Possible to match multiple conditions in one case statement?

